# Unable to build android project after update kotlin to 1.2.21

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I am unable to build my project after updating kotlin version to 1.2.21. I was looking for a solution for a long time but without any success. My previous kotlin version was 1.1.2-4, and it was working like a charm. Some time ago I was trying to update kotlin to the newer version ( different/lower than 1.2.21) but I also finished with no success. After that I decided to leave it as it was, but now I have to update kotlin because I want to use new features from the recent version.

Here is my error:

```
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/damiankwasniak/Workspace/foodtruck_android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/0.jar

com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/damiankwasniak/Workspace/foodtruck_android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/0.jar
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:235)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2121.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/damiankwasniak/Workspace/foodtruck_android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/0.jar
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:550)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$1(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:488)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing com/lignt/domain/api/models/foodtruck/LocationResponseModel.class

at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:143)
at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.convert(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:89)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:545)
... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext
at com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:45)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:398)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:150)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:102)
at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.dex(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:107)
at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.convert(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:86)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        custom {
            keyAlias '"androiddebugkey"'
            keyPassword '"android"'
            storeFile file('/home/avonil/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword '"android"'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lignt.foodtrack"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':domain')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    def SUPPORT_VERSION = '27.0.2'


    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:' + SUPPORT_VERSION
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + SUPPORT_VERSION
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:' + SUPPORT_VERSION
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:' + SUPPORT_VERSION
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:' + SUPPORT_VERSION


    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.Zhuinden:simple-stack:1.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'blue.aodev:material-values:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'nz.bradcampbell:paperparcel:2.0.1'
    implementation 'nz.bradcampbell:paperparcel-kotlin:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.eyalbira.loadingdots:loading-dots:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:airmapview:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann:adapterdelegates3:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13"

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'org.amshove.kluent:kluent:1.14'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0'

}
```

I also have got java/kotlin module in my project, but it is probably not a case because updating kotlin version in this module has no impact for building the project.

Here is the gradle file for kotlin module:

```
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:1.0.0'
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile 'org.amshove.kluent:kluent:1.14'
    testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
}


kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Please add the code for LocationResponseModel, since the exception happens while processing it

Comment: do you have latest version of kotlin plugin installed? Preferences->Plugins->Kotlin

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Yes, I do. I updated kotlin plugin yesterday to Version: 1.2.21-release-Studio3.0-1

Comment: @Vaiden I think it is not relevant. The classes printed in this log are random, but here is the [code](https://pastebin.com/CkGM0XgJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion with @Sparow199 we found the solution. The problem was kotlin module which was added as a dependency in android module. In kotlin modul's gradle file, there was a line:

```
kapt {
generateStubs = true
}
```

It looks like there is no more need to generate stubs for kotlin classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android.enableD8=true` to gradle.properties and replace `compile` with `implementation`

Comment: It doesn't work, but I have a new [error](https://pastebin.com/WRw9F9md)

Comment: Try to remove apply plugin kapt from Gradle

Comment: I need kapt for dagger, which I have in dependencies.

Comment: Previous log is in my original post. Log after enabling D8 is in the first comment. Here is the link: https://pastebin.com/WRw9F9md

Comment: try to add :    defaultConfig {multiDexEnabled true } to you app/build.gradle.heve you enabled Advanced profiling in your run/debug Configuration ?

Comment: I have multidex enabled in my gradle file. I also have advanced profiling enabled.

Comment: You have to disable advanced profiling, and clean your project and rebuild

Comment: I think that you have to check and update all your dependencies versions, replace testCompile by testImplementation, may be you have some of your dependencies which require Java 7 and your are using only Java 8 in your build script. 

compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

Comment: Try also to clean deeply your Gradle cash: Inside Android Studio, went to File > Invalidate caches / Restart... and invalidated the caches and restarted it.

Comment: I changed compileOptions to :

 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }, but I still have the same problem. The compiler complains for domain.jar file which is set as dependency in gradle file.

Comment: Try to remove your_app/.gradle/ folder, before close Android studio and reimport your project.

Comment: Replace your mavenCentral repository by adding google() 

jcenter()

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Comment: I removed whole domain module from the project ( kotlin module) and  the project is compiling with no problem. There is a problem between these two modules ;/

Comment: Congratulations for resolving your problem :-)

Comment: It didn't resolve my problem because I want to have domain logic separate for the rest of the application. Happily  I found this line: kapt {
    generateStubs = true
} . Probably it should be use with current kotlin version and it was causing the problem. Thank you a lot for help and your time :)